# Check if a TextBlocks text is a certain Color

Tags: c#, microsoft-metro

Is there anyway to check if a `TextBlock`'s text is a certain Color.
What I mean is, is there a way to say:

```
if(textblocks foreground is blue)
//do stuff
```

While I'm at it does anyone know how to change a `TextBlock`'s foreground randomly?

Comment: @McAuley...is this asp.net, mvc....which version of the .Net framework?

Comment: @ MikeTWebb  Its an app for windows 8

Comment: is it not governed by ForeColor or even Color?

Comment: The code will be different based on the type of app.  Is it a web app, a desktop app?

Comment: Oh I see, Its a Desktop App

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you're using a `SolidColorBrush`, you can try this

```
SolidColorBrush b = myTextBlock.Foreground as SolidColorBrush;
if (b != null)
{
   if(b.Color == Windows.UI.Colors.Blue)
   {
      //your code
   }
}
```

To set a random colour, you can choose a random colour to pick and set it. You can use `Random` as below, or select from `KnownColor` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805774/how-to-generate-random-color-names-in-c-sharp).

```
Random rnd = new Random();     

myTextBlock.Foreground = new SolidColorBrush
                   (Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255), rnd.Next(255)));
```

Comment: I had to say if (b.Color == Windows.UI.Colors.Blue) But it worked! Thank you!

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I'll update the answer. If this has answered your question, you can press the "tick" mark on the left.