# How to randomly color gridview(each row by a random color)

Tags: c#, css, asp.net, gridview, random

I need some help in solving this task.
I need to color each and every record in a gridview randomly with a unique color.

Example:

Suppose if i have ten rows in a gridview i want to color each row randomly with a different color.

So the output should be like first row colored in red and second row in yellow and so on.

If i take 100 rows in a gridview all 100 rows should be colored uniquely.

Can you guys please help.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Do you have the code to change the color of 1 row in a `GridView` written yet?  If not I would start by figuring that out, and then worrying about the next step after.

Comment: You can use this javaScript Library to generate random colours http://www.checkman.io/please/

Answer (score 2):

Combine these two questions:

[How to change row color in datagridview?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2189376/c-sharp-how-to-change-row-color-in-datagridview)

[How to generate random color names in C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805774/how-to-generate-random-color-names-in-c-sharp)

```
foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dgv.Rows) 
{
    row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = getRandomColor();
}

private Color getRandomColor()
{

    Random randomGen = new Random();
    KnownColor[] names = (KnownColor[]) Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor));
    KnownColor randomColorName = names[randomGen.Next(names.Length)];
    return  Color.FromKnownColor(randomColorName);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this way

```
    List<string> UsedColors = new List<string>();

    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        foreach (DataGridViewRow row in dataGridView1.Rows)
            row.DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = RandColor();
    }

    private Color RandColor()
    {
        Random x = new Random();
                int r,g,b;
        Color myRgbColor = new Color();
        while(true)
        {
            r = x.Next(0,255);
            g = x.Next(0,255);
            b = x.Next(0,255);
            if(!UsedColors.Contains( r + "," + g + "," + b ))
            {
                UsedColors.Add( r + "," + g + "," + b );
                break;
            }
        }
        myRgbColor = Color.FromArgb( r , g , b );
        return myRgbColor;
    }
```

Comment: This does not fit the requirements. It has been asked to have different colors for each row. So no duplicates. Your code however allows duplicates. Also "clicking" was not part of the question.

Comment: You could use a `do-while` instead of the "infinite" while-loop with the conditional break. Anyway, this should work.