# Need help randomly pick colors for Bing Maps WPF Control regions

Tags: c#, wpf, colors, bing-maps

I am using the [Bing Maps WPF Control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh750210.aspx) in C# to draw some regions over the US that various salespeople cover.  I'm able to draw the regions just fine and I use a [function similar to this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5805844/643619) to randomly pick a color from `System.Drawing.KnownColor`, which all works fine.

This issue I'm running into is since its random, you get a lot of colors that are very close on regions touching each other (ie region 1 borders 2, and region 1 is purple and region 2 is every-so-slightly darker purple so they end up bleeding together).

Is there some RGB math I can do on regions touching each other to ensure the values of the colors are significantly different?  Also, is there a way to exclude certain shades altogether (ex: the background of the map is white, so all shades of white should probably be unpickable)?

Comment: How many regions in total you might possibly end up with?

Comment: One of the problems you are getting into is depending if your regions are zips, counties, states, etc.  Is they are all going to be dependent on each other.  EG: If I change the color of Oregon because it borders California closely and it changes then it may be close to Washington whose color is then close.  So you then create a problem of x changes y but did not count on z, so you in essence need to differentiate all objects that collide are different.  An idea may be to go North to South or East to West, etc.  And create a gradient that slightly changes as a vector changes.

Comment: @FirstStep Right now there's 22, it'll fluctuate by one or two either direction as people are hired and fired.

Comment: Why don't you pick the colors yourself when a conflict occurs?

Comment: @FirstStep well I'd like it to be automated so I don't have to fiddle with it every time there's a new hire.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that using only four colors for whatever the size / number of your regions and it is called [**The Four Colors Theorem**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Four_color_theorem). It is easy to implement if you get a strong understanding of it. But you can find codes provided already online such as:
[Graph Colouring With Simple Backtracking](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/ericlippert/2010/07/12/graph-colouring-with-simple-backtracking-part-one/). Which, like any other online code, would need some tuning to solve your problem.

Also, you would like to take a look at the theory behind [Graph Coloring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Graph_coloring).

I can also think of these:

- Why don't you (The end user) manually pick another color when a conflict occurs?
- Program it to find "the / any" two connected boarders that have small colors delta between them, and call the `GenerateRandomColor()` again to pick a new color. Let the algorithm keep doing it till all requirements are reached (all colors are different = all colors' delta' are above the threshold)
- On every Color picked, make sure that, for example, some range [+x, -x] around that color, and including that color, should not be picked anymore.

Hint: Treat your colors as numbers (Something like rainbow -> 0 to 1000), and then **create** a color using that int / hex .. etc).

Personally, I would just get rid of this whole random-ness thing, because the problem is not that complicated, it is not a good design and because it is not worth it. I would just prepare a small text file that has 30 different Colors in RGB values. Load it on application load and use it to assign each employee a different color. Once they get more than 30, I will just modify and add more colors to that text file.

Comment: This is great, but I'm not sure it will quite fit the user requirements.  They want to know that Bob is Green, so its easy to find Bob on the map, if there's more than one green they could get confused, unless maybe make the other greens that result from the Four Color Theorem different shades of green?

Comment: Thanks! What do you think is the best way to check if its +/-x within a color range? Not too up on colors.  Say I wanted RGB values to be > 64 apart, would I check all three (R, G, and B) for > 64 or just one or the sum of them?

Comment: I would just get rid of this whole random-ness thing, because the problem is not that complicated, it is not a good design and because it is not worth it. I would just prepare a small text file that has 30 different Colors in RGB values. Load it on application load and use it to assign each employee a different color. Once they get more than 30, I will just modify and add more colors to that text file.

Comment: But my profound laziness! Yeah I know you're right... Just thought it could be an interesting problem to try to solve but the time investment is probably not worth it.