# Get all Definitions at once in c#

Tags: c#

In CMD language you can define all at once like:`del C:\randomfiles\*`
That Means you select ALL files at once. I have the Code `var names = new List<System.Drawing.Color> { Red, DarkRed, 1000 colors later... };` but I dont want to tipe in all colors because that may take years... How can I define all at once like in CMD language? 
EDIT: This is not the same as: [How do I enumerate an enum?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/105372/how-do-i-enumerate-an-enum) because I want al ist of all colors WITHOUT spending years writing all colors....

Comment: I want to list all the colors without writing tons of code because there are over 100 colors.

Comment: You use an inappropriate example, using wrong terms, to ask something unrelated.  Your question has nothing to do with "How do I retrieve a list of all defined colors"?

Comment: no need for list if just a random color is needed http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805774/how-to-generate-random-color-names-in-c-sharp

Comment: My mistake, it's not an enum - but there's an exact duplicate question. (But your reasoning in the edit was off - it's not a duplicate of that because `System.Drawing.Color` isn't an enum, not because you want a list without writing them all out...)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To create a list of all colors you can use something like this

```
List<Color> allColors = new List<Color>();
foreach (KnownColor col in Enum.GetValues(typeof(KnownColor)))
{
    Color c = Color.FromKnownColor(col);
    if(!c.IsSystemColor)
        allColors.Add(c);
}
```

[KnownColor](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.knowncolor(v=vs.110).aspx) is an enum and this will allow us to traverse all the definitions using a simple foreach.

Of course, if you want also the system colors (WindowText, ControlText, etc...) remove the check on IsSystemColor

Comment: It gives me the error:`The Type "System.Collections.Generic.List <System.Drawing.Color>" can not be implicitly converted to "System.Drawing.Color".`

Comment: Uhm, are you sure? Just checked this in LinqPad and there is no such error in the code above.

Comment: `button1.ForeColor = allColors;` gives the error

Comment: You should assign a single color to ForeColor not the whole list. It seems that you have not explained well what are you trying to do here.

Comment: uhh i forgot about this code sorry `int indexpick = randomcolor.Next(allColors.Count);
            var name = allColors[indexpick];` now it worked thank you