# How do I change Brush color randomly using a timer?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, gdi+

I have an ellipse within my winform whose fill property I am trying to randomly change, i.e. I want the color of my ellipse to keep on changing constantly.

```
SolidBrush colour;

 private void drawBorder()
    {
        Pen bPen = new Pen(Color.Black, 8);
        colour = new SolidBrush(Color.Yellow);

        g.DrawEllipse(bPen, 412, 269, 19, 19);
        g.FillEllipse(colour, 412, 269, 19, 19);

        timer1.Enabled = true;
        timer1.Start();
    }


private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //g.FillEllipse(colour, 412, 269, 19, 19);

        if (this.colour.Color == Color.Yellow)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("!", Color.Yellow.ToString());
            this.colour.Color = Color.Pink;
        }
        if (this.colour.Color == Color.Pink)
        {
            //MessageBox.Show("#", this.colour.Color.ToString());
            this.colour.Color = Color.Yellow;
        }
    }
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5805774/how-to-generate-random-color-names-in-c-sharp

Answer (score 3):

Declare the Random class at the form level and use the Color.FromArgb function to create your color:

```
private Color colour = Color.Black;
private Random rnd = new Random();

private void timer1_Tick(object sender, EventArgs e) {
  colour = Color.FromArgb(rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256), rnd.Next(256));
  this.Invalidate();
}

protected override void OnPaint(PaintEventArgs e) {      
  base.OnPaint(e);

  e.Graphics.Clear(Color.White);
  e.Graphics.SmoothingMode = SmoothingMode.AntiAlias;
  using (SolidBrush br = new SolidBrush(colour)) {
    e.Graphics.FillEllipse(br, new Rectangle(16, 16, 64, 64));
  }
}
```

Comment: You probably just want to invalidate a rectangle that circumscribes the ellipse (rather then the entire form). You'll get less flicker that way

Comment: @Flydog57 Just DoubleBuffer the form.  It's not clear from the question if the Ellipse is a shape or a drawing, but they included the tag GDI+, so I assumed a drawing.

Comment: I get an error saying "Cannot convert System.Drawing.SolidBrush to System.Drawing.Color. "

Comment: @AdithiChakravarthy My posted code does not generate that error.  Edit your question with the code you are using.

Comment: @LarsTech I have edited my code. Thank you for helping.

Comment: @AdithiChakravarthy A lot of things wrong in your code, but to start, I have colour declared as a Color, not a Brush.  Try it my way and just use your Rectangle coordinates in its place.  Dispose your pen, too.  Don't store the graphic object, always get it from the Paint event.

Comment: Thank you so much! Yes, my code is a little more complicated than it needs to be. I am working on fixing it.